# Vue 3 template ref in composable

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api, vue-mixin

I want to switch from Options API to Composition API and use composables in place of mixin. So far I've been using a global mixin with computed property like this:

```
// globalMixin.js

 computed: {
    myAlert() {
        return this.$refs.myAlertDiv;
    }
 }
```

Then I used this mixin when creating app:

```
// MyApp.js

const MyApp = {
   mixins: [globalMixin]
...
}
```

myAlert became MyApp's computed property and I could use it without declaring directly inside MyApp properties.

Now I want to achieve the same result with composables, let's say I have a component importing a composable:

```
// App.vue

<script setup>
import { useGlobalComposable} from './globalComposable.js';

const globalComposable = useGlobalComposable();

onMounted(() => {

// should work without declaring myAlert inside App.vue
console.log(globalComposable.myAlert);
})
...
</script>
```

Is it possible to do? If so, how should I declare myAlert template ref inside composable?

Comment: Should be `const { myAlert } = useGlobalComposable()`. This is how it's done with composition api

Answer (score 0):

Your `useGlobalComposable` function should return `myAlert`, like this:

```
const useGlobalComposable = function() { 
  
   const myAlertDiv = ....

   const myAlert = computed(() => {
        return myAlertDiv;
    });

   return {myAlert}
  }
```

Then you can declare myAlert in the setup block

```
 const { myAlert } = useComposable();   
 return { myAlert }
```

Note, that `this.$refs` from the `mixin` will not work directly with the Composition API. If you create a component, then you can use `this` to access the component properties and methods.

Here is a good article about [using `refs` with Composition API](https://dev.to/zelig880/how-to-use-refs-in-vue-3-with-composition-api-and-script-setup-121n).

Very simple working example of using a composable in `setup`:

```js
 const { ref, reactive, createApp } = Vue;
 
 const useComposable = function() { 
  const test = ref(1);
  return { test }; 
 }
 
 const App = { 
   setup() {    
      const { test } = useComposable();   
      return { test }
   }
}
 
 const app = createApp(App)
 app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div>Test: {{ test }}</div>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Comment: If your composable returns _multiple_ things and you want to extract only one (or more) refs to return from `setup`, you can use destructuring and the spread operator to do `const { test, ...everythingElse } = useComposable();`